# How do I scale one operand of a vector addition to get sum of a given magnitude?

Tags: vectors

Vector A + Vector B = Vector C

- Vector A is known
- The normal of Vector B is known
- The magnitude of Vector C is known

I'm looking for the scalar coefficient x I can multiply B with so that A + xB = C where |C| is the known magnitude.

On the request of a replier, here's a diagram:
[image]

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. $A+xB$ is a vector and $|C|$ is a scalar. They can't be equal. Please [edit] the question to clarify. If you can post a picture of what you want we may be able to help.

Comment: I did my best to try and clean this up. I'll see what I can draw. This is hard for me to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write $|A+xB|=c$ where $c$ is the known magnitude of $C$, which means that (by squaring both sides of the equation and using the inner produc $v\cdot v=|v|^2$)

$$|A|^2+x^2|B|^2+2(A\cdot B)x=c^2$$

This is a quadratic equation which gives you the solutions for $x$, which is $\frac{-2(A\cdot B)\pm\sqrt{4(A\cdot B)^2-4|B|^2(|A|^2-c^2)}}{2|B|^2}$, and there is no solution if $4(A\cdot B)^2-4|B|^2(|A|^2-c^2)<0$.

Geometrically, let $A=\vec{PQ}$, then you can draw a circle centered at $P$ with radius $c$ and a line passing by $Q$ in the direction of $B$. This line can intersect with the circle at $0,1$ or $2$ points and would give you the correct vector $xB$. (Or you can draw a circle centered at $Q$ and a line passing by $P$, too).

Comment: Hmmm... This is all really good, but I'm not certain how quadratics works anymore, so it''s unclear to me how I'd solve for x in the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

If $A + xB  = C$,  then $xB = C-A$, so you can take the norm of both sides and get

$$ ||C - A|| = || xB ||= |x| \cdot ||B||,$$ which yields

$$ |x| = \frac{||C-A||}{||B||}.$$

So you just have to test the two possible values of $x$ (positive and negative) and see which one works.

HOWEVER, your equation doesn't always have a solution. You need to have $C-A$ and $B$ be vectors pointing in the identical direction. If they aren't then this equation will give you values of $x$, but neither one will satisfy your original equation. You could test that they point the same way (i.e. are "parallel" vectors) before you compute the values of $x$, but since you have to check both the positive and negative options anyways I'd just find my $x$'s, compute $A+ xB$, and see if either value works.

There is an interesting question of whether you could compute $x$ via a formula that doesn't require checking at the end, but I doesn't look like you care about that in you situation.

Comment: Is ||C|| - ||A|| the same as ||C - A||? Because I only have ||C||, not C.

Comment: Dang it, I missed that in your question. No, it's not, so my answer is useless in your situation. With the information you have you're going to have to solve a quadratic in the end, no matter what. @quangtu123's answer looks good -- I'd spend the time understanding it, and ask them for clarifications if you need them.